# Add data points in an existing plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colorbar

I have the following problem: Initially I have constructed a plot that involves four different classes of data points, as shown in the below figure:
[image]

which is created through the following code:

```
 Wells = as.factor(xyClust$group)
      my_colors <- c("red", "blue", "magenta","orange",'black')
      p <- ggplot(data = xyClust, aes(x = x, y = y, color = Wells ) )  +
        geom_point(size=6) +
        scale_color_manual(values = my_colors) +
        #scale_discrete_manual(values = my_colors,names="aa") +
        theme_bw()
      p1 <- p +  geom_point(data = laa, aes(x=X, y=Y,color='borders') ) 
      p1
```

What I want to do, is to separate the black points from the remaining ones, since they represent the border of the region, thus they should not appear in the side colour bar.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? [How can I drop a used value from the legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68196365/how-can-i-drop-a-used-value-from-the-legend/68196485#68196485)

Comment: @stefan Hi Stefan. Thanks for your response. Indeed it is a useful link. I will have it in mind for future activities

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found the answer. I just move the details withini ggplot into geom_point as follow;

```
my_colors2 <- c("red", "blue", "magenta","orange")
      p2 <- ggplot( )  +
        geom_point(data = xyClust, aes(x = x, y = y, color = Wells),size=6) +
        scale_color_manual(values = my_colors2) +
        theme_bw()
      p3 <- p2 +  geom_point(data = laa, aes(x=X, y=Y) ) +
        labs(x = "x (m)", y = "y (m)") + 
        theme(axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 14, face = "bold"),
              axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 14, face = "bold"),
              axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 14),
              axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 14) )
      p3
```

[image]